# Compilation 'pauses' and expects input, but there is no error message

Tags: compiling

When I try to compile the MWE below with `xelatex`, I get the following:

```
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
)
*
```

The * seems to be a prompt: pressing ENTER gives

```
*
(Please type a command or say `\end')
*
(Please type a command or say `\end')
*
(Please type a command or say `\end')
*
```

The .log file isn't useful. Leaving aside whatever the actual error in my document is, I don't understand what's happening: why is LaTeX pausing in this fashion without emitting any error?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,hmargin={1.2cm,1cm},vmargin=1cm,footskip=7mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter

\begingroup
\lccode`\~`\\
\lowercase{\endgroup
\def\vb{%
\par
\parindent\z@
\parskip1\baselineskip plus 2pt\relax
\let\do\@makeother\dospecials%
\let\@xobeysp\space
\catcode`\ \active
\catcode`\\\active
\let~\scanendvb
}}
\def\scanendvb#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
\def\x{#1#2#3#4#5#6#7}%
\ifx\x\endvbstr
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{\end{vb}}{\char`\\#1#2#3#4#5#6#7}}

\edef\endvbstr{end\string{vb\string}}

\makeatother
\def\endvb{\par}

\newenvironment{almsinp}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}\begin{vb}}{\end{vb}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\begin{almsinp}
Definition 2.1.2.
A _metric space_ M = (A, d) consists of a non-empty set A together with a map d : A\times A -> \bfR such that:
    (M1a) d(x, y)\geq 0 for all x, y in A.
    (M1b) d(x, y) = 0 <=>  x = y  for all x, y in A.
    (M2) d(x, y) = d(y, x) for all x, y in A.
    (M3) d(x, y)+d(y, z)\geq d(x, z) for all x, y, z in A.
The elements of A are called the _points_ of the metric space M, and d is called a _metric_ on A. We sometimes also call d the _metric_ of M.
\end{almsinp}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use the `vb` environment as argument to other commands. It's a limitation holding for all "verbatim-type" environments.

Comment: Looks like you are reading verbatim and failing to close it correctly :-) As a result LaTeX is getting to the end of the file and waiting for more input, which is what TeX does when it has not reached an error or something to end the run (run TeX interactively to see this).

Comment: egreg's answer led me to an explanation of the phenomenon at  http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `vb` environment in the argument to another command, as it's always the case with "verbatim-like" commands. I suggest you to add an optional argument to `vb` and change its definition so it uses a `minipage`. But you have to realize that this will prohibit page breaks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,hmargin={1.2cm,1cm},vmargin=1cm,footskip=7mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\makeatletter

\begingroup
\lccode`\~`\\
\catcode`!\active
\lccode`!=`\^^M
\lowercase{\endgroup
\newcommand\vb[1][\textwidth]{%
\par\noindent\minipage[t]{#1}
\parskip1\baselineskip plus 2pt\relax
\let\do\@makeother\dospecials%
\let\@xobeysp\space
\catcode`\ \active
\catcode`\\\active
\catcode`\^^M\active
\def!{\par\leavevmode}
\let~\scanendvb
}}
\def\scanendvb#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
\def\x{#1#2#3#4#5#6#7}%
\ifx\x\endvbstr
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{\end{vb}}{\char`\\#1#2#3#4#5#6#7}}

\edef\endvbstr{end\string{vb\string}}

\makeatother
\def\endvb{\endminipage}

\begin{document}
\begin{vb}[.5\textwidth]
Definition 2.1.2.
A _metric space_ M = (A, d) consists of a non-empty set A together with a map d : A\times A -> \bfR such that:
    (M1a) d(x, y)\geq 0 for all x, y in A.
    (M1b) d(x, y) = 0 <=>  x = y  for all x, y in A.
    (M2) d(x, y) = d(y, x) for all x, y in A.
    (M3) d(x, y)+d(y, z)\geq d(x, z) for all x, y, z in A.
The elements of A are called the _points_ of the metric space M, and d is called a _metric_ on A. We sometimes also call d the _metric_ of M.
\end{vb}
\end{document}
```

By the way, this incorporates some changes so as to get line breaks at each end-of-line.

Note that loading `fontenc` when using `fontspec` is generally not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and it was simply that I forgot the `\end{document}` at the end.  Adding it solved the problem.  Found this answer elsewhere and copying it here for future reference.